# Conversion method for musical intervals to notes, running into NumberFormatException

Tags: java, methods, type-conversion, numberformatexception

I am working on a method whose parameters are a String of musical intervals and a String root note. For example, the minor scale in music is the following intervals:

`1 2 b3 4 5 b6 b7 8` and given root note C the output should be:

```
C4 D4 Eb4 F4 G4 Ab4 Bb4 C5
```

I am trying to include all altered intervals as well, `ex: b9, #9, b5, b11, b13.` Base octave is assumed to be 4. If the interval is greater than an octave, it should add however many octaves it spans to 4. Theoretically the method should be able to process extremely large intervals into notes, for instance an interval of 1400, which would surpass the range of human hearing.

How am I trying to do this? I have created a local variable String 'interval' to store each interval in individually for processing, a local variable 'noteValue' to hold the interval value in half-steps, and a local variable 'notes' to contain the converted notes. I take the input string of all the intervals, and create a substring "c" for each position i in a for loop. I test whether the character in that substring is a number 0-9, a 'b' (flat sign), or a '#' (sharp sign). Else, it is assumed that a space has been encountered and the local variable 'interval' goes on to processing.

If the character of String c is a digit 0-9, it is added to the String interval. If the character of String c is 'b' noteValue is decremented and if it is '#' noteValue is incremented, each by one.

For instance, if a b13 interval is entered, the 'b' should be processed and decrement noteValue by one. The '1' should then be added to String of name interval. The '3' is then read and added to the String of name interval. After the character in substring c is not a digit, 'b' or '#', the String interval with a value of "13" goes on to be converted to half-steps. It is parsed into an
Integer and converted according to the half step values of the major scale (which all intervals are compared to). The half step value of a b13 should be an octave (12) + a b6 (8) = 20.

Assuming the root note was a C, the b13 should return an Ab. This is done using a series of if statements to find the proper root note, each of which contains a switch. By applying the %12 operation to find the note value from 0 to 11 possible half step positions, the note value is determined and added to the notes String. Once the entire intervalString parameter has been processed, the notes String should be returned.

I am running into a problem with a NumberFormatException at line 38, where I try to parse the 'interval' String to an Integer. I have put a println() statement to see what is happening and it appears that the String interval is not properly updating. Not really sure where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
public class testIntervals {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new testIntervals();
}
public testIntervals() {
    String intervals = "1 2 b3 4 5 b6 b7 8";
    String rootNote = "C";
    String notes = intervalsToNotes(intervals, rootNote);
    System.out.println(notes);
}
public String intervalsToNotes(String intervalString, String rootNote) {
    int noteValue = 0;
    int octave = 4;
    String interval = "";
    String notes = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < intervalString.length(); i++) {
        String c = intervalString.substring(i);
        System.out.println(c);
        if (c.charAt(0) >= '0' && c.charAt(0) <= '9')
            interval = interval.concat(c);
        else if (c.charAt(0) == 'b')
            noteValue--;
        else if (c.charAt(0) == '#')
            noteValue++;
        else {
            System.out.println(interval + c);
            int process = Integer.parseInt(interval);
            interval = "";
            for (int j = 1; i <= process; i++) {
                if (j%7 == 2 || j%7 == 3 || j%7 == 5 || j%7 == 6 || j%7 == 0) {
                    noteValue += 2;
                }
                else if (j%7 == 1 || j%7 == 4) {
                    noteValue++;
                }
            }
            octave += (noteValue / 12);
            if (rootNote.equals("Ab") || rootNote.equals("G#")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("Bb" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("Db" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("Eb" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("Gb" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("A")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("Bb" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("A#") || rootNote.equals("Bb")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("Db" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("Eb" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("Gb" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("Ab" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("B") || rootNote.equals("Cb")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("B#") || rootNote.equals("C")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("C#") || rootNote.equals("Db")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("D")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("D#") || rootNote.equals("Eb")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("E") || rootNote.equals("Fb")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("E#") || rootNote.equals("F")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("F#") || rootNote.equals("Gb")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("G" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
            else if (rootNote.equals("G")) {
                switch (noteValue % 12) {

                case 0: notes = notes.concat(rootNote + octave + " ");break;
                case 1: notes = notes.concat("G#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 2: notes = notes.concat("A" + octave + " ");break;
                case 3: notes = notes.concat("A#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 4: notes = notes.concat("B" + octave + " ");break;
                case 5: notes = notes.concat("C" + octave + " ");break;
                case 6: notes = notes.concat("C#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 7: notes = notes.concat("D" + octave + " ");break;
                case 8: notes = notes.concat("D#" + octave + " ");break;
                case 9: notes = notes.concat("E" + octave + " ");break;
                case 10: notes = notes.concat("F" + octave + " ");break;
                case 11: notes = notes.concat("F#" + octave + " ");break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return notes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally concat a non-convertable string: `interval = interval.concat(c);` (line 31). I think it should be `interval = interval.concat(c.charAt(0));`